# Create new thread for a new JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm learning about threads and I've got a problem with it. I'm trying to make 2 frames, one is a main frame and another will be shown later after clicking on a button. I want to stop the main frame while the new frame is running. Can you guys help me with a very simple example for this? (And the new frame will be closed after clicking on a button too). Just 2 frames with a button on each are enough. Much appreciated!

Comment: You have to [learn about Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). Especially the part about [dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Comment: I know about dialogs but I'm asking for my Alarm application

Comment: And what problem do you have? Are you really expecting pepole to write code for you? Such questions are completely off-topic on SO!

Comment: Yes I am expecting people to help me, that's what SO is all about right? I can't really describe my problems and my code is just too long, too ugly to read so I'm asking for a little example, that's all.

Comment: *"Yes I am expecting people to help me, that's what SO is all about right?"*  Wrong!  SO is a Q&A site, where what you seek seems more a tutor or help desk.

Comment: *"I want to stop the main frame while the new frame is running"* - Dialog. Also, remember, Swing is single threaded and not thread safe, all updates to the UI MUST be made from within the context of the EDT

Answer (score 5):

You should avoid [the use of multiple `JFrame`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice/9554657#9554657), use modal [dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) instead. [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) offers a ton of good, easy & flexible methods to do so.

Here's an example. When you click the button the dialog will appear on top of the `JFrame`. The main `JFrame` won't be clickable anymore, since `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` produces a [modal window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window).

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Example {

    public Example() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "I'm a dialog!");
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I like the use of the gif